# How to correctly quote CMAKE Join Generator expressions

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command, cmake-language

Consider a target with compile options and include files:

```
target_compile_options(Tutorial PRIVATE /DC=1)
target_compile_options(Tutorial PRIVATE /DD=2)
target_include_directories(Tutorial PRIVATE "include files/a")
target_include_directories(Tutorial PRIVATE "include files/b")
```

And a custom command that wants to do something special:

```
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT Tutorial.i
   COMMAND "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}" -I"$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Tutorial,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>,\" -I\">" "$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Tutorial,COMPILE_OPTIONS>,\" \">" /P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Tutorial.cxx
   MAIN_DEPENDENCY "Tutorial.cxx"
   COMMENT "Preprocessing Tutorial.cxx"
   )
```

This correctly quotes the include folders:

```
-I"include files/a" -I"include files/b"
```

Note the `"` marks immediately before and after the `$<JOIN...>` expression show up in the output.

However, the compile options come out without the leading and trailing `"` like this:

```
/DC=1" "/DD=2
```

On the other hand, if the generator expression for the compile options is this:

```
"$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Tutorial,COMPILE_OPTIONS>, >"
```

Then, the result is this where the outer quotes are retained.

```
"/DC=1 /DD=2"
```

Neither are what I need - which is each option quoted separately. This can be fixed by expressly including first and last quotes:

```
"\"$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Tutorial,COMPILE_OPTIONS>, >\""
```

What I don't understand is why the two `JOIN` expressions behave differently about retaining or dropping the surrounding double quotes?

P.S> And if the `$<JOIN` isn't surrounded in quotes at all, then it doesn't seem to be processed `$<JOIN...>` actually shows up in the command line.

This can be reproduced starting with the CMake Tutorial step 4 and adding the option and custom command lines above.

Comment: You might want to try out what behaviour is like with the [`VERBATIM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) option and see how that differs. What platform are you on and what build tools are you using? Please [edit] if you add that info.